# MySQL return multple row values in one select

Tags: mysql, return, row

I am trying to prepare a report from my database.

I have 2 tables like so:

```
device          sensor
id  | name      id  | devid | value
====|=====      ====|=======|========
1   | dev1      1   |   1   | 1.1
2   | dev2      2   |   1   | 1.2
                3   |   2   | 2.1
                4   |   2   | 2.2
```

I want to get a return of this:

```
 id | name  | val_rc    | val_cf
====|=======|===========|==========
 1  | dev1  | 1.1       | 1.2
 2  | dev2  | 2.1       | 2.2
```

I am using a for statement to put all the values into my report.  The header names are not important.

I have tried different permutations of this SQL query:

```
SELECT device.id, device.name, sensor.value AS val_rc, sensor.value AS val_cf
FROM device
JOIN sensor
ON sensor.devid = device.id;
```

Comment: what decides `rc` or `cf` values?

Comment: @bluefeet value column...rc and cf are aliases

Comment: Does each `devid` has exactly two values related in `sensor` table?

Comment: Is the the table scada.sensor or scada.curval?

Comment: @Mr.Alien right but how is it decided which value for which column?  Something must distinguish between the values.

Comment: @bluefeet I guess he is using id's as primary/foreign...

Comment: sorry I left my old tables in the sql statement.  it's fixed now

Comment: @posop you need to provide more details, how do you determine which record goes in the `rc` and the `cf` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided no details about how you want to decide which value goes in each column, so this example uses a `row_number`:

```
select id,
   name,
   max(case when GROUP_ROW_NUMBER = 1 then value end) as val_rc,
   max(case when GROUP_ROW_NUMBER = 2 then value end) as val_cf
from
(
  select d.id, devid, name, value, 
        @num := if(@NAME = `NAME`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,
        @NAME := `NAME` as dummy
  FROM device d
  INNER JOIN sensor s
    ON s.devid = d.id
  order by name, value
) x
group by id, name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/132e3/32)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table `device` twice with `sensor`.

Assuming you want the value for `rc` to be the first value in the table and `cf` the last one, this query :

```
SELECT device.id, device.name, sensor1.value AS val_rc, sensor2.value AS val_cf
FROM device, sensor sensor1, sensor sensor2
    where sensor1.devid= device.id 
    and sensor1.id = (select min(id) from sensor s1 where s1.devid= sensor1.devid)
    and sensor2.devid= device.id 
    and sensor2.id = (select max(id) from sensor s2 where s2.devid= sensor2.devid)
```

will give exactly what you asked.

```
 id | name  | val_rc    | val_cf
====|=======|===========|==========
 1  | dev1  | 1.1       | 1.2
 2  | dev2  | 2.1       | 2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at what you wrote here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT device.id, device.name,
(SELECT sensor.value FROM sensor WHERE sensor.devid = device.id AND sensor.senid = '1') AS val_rc, 
(SELECT sensor.value FROM sensor WHERE sensor.devid = device.id AND sensor.senid = '2') AS val_cf  
FROM device
```